# Accessing Json object information

Tags: android, json

I am developing an android app, in that i have to make a call to my remote server,it will give me data in terms of json object. in following format.

```
       {
-source: {
LS: " ABCDEF",
name: "XYXA",
point: "77.583859,12.928751"
},
 -stores: [
    -{
    ph: null,
    distance: "0.3",
    LS: " abcd",
    id: 1209,
    name: "xyz",
    point: "77.583835,12.926359"
    },
-{
    ph: null,
    distance: "0.3",
    LS: " abcd",
    id: 1209,
    name: "xyz",
    point: "77.583835,12.926359"
    }
    ]
}
```

i have confirmed that server is giving me response. But i'm not getting how to access this data in my application.

Can anybody give me a code to access these data.?

Thanking you

Comment: You can also visit the json home page find how to parse json in java.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Show ur code

Comment: Are you getting response in JSON format or in plain text ? @dharshan

Comment: Please give the valid json object response to get accurate solution.

Comment: @GrisHu i'm getting response in json format..

i think in my source code,response is converted into json.

this application is already developed. But it is making use of Google map v1. but now i have to convert it into v2.Thats y i need to know how to parse this response to get only points in the format lat and long

Comment: @dharshan Can you show your exact JSON response ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
                     JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(responseString);
                     String LS=jsonObject.getJSONObject("source").get("LS").toString();
                     String name=jsonObject.getJSONObject("source").get("name").toString();
                     String point=jsonObject.getJSONObject("source").get("point").toString();
                     String[] latlng = point.split(",");
                     String lat=latlng[0];
                     String lng=latlng[1];
                     System.out.println("Lat "+lat+" Lng "+lng);
                     JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("stores");
                     if (jsonArray.length()>0)
                     {
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) 
                        {
                             JSONObject jsonObject1=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                             String ph=jsonObject1.get("ph").toString();
                             String distance=jsonObject1.get("distance").toString();
                             String LS=jsonObject1.get("LS").toString();
                             String id=jsonObject1.get("id").toString();
                             String name=jsonObject1.get("name").toString();
                             String point=jsonObject1.get("point").toString();
                             String[] latlng = point.split(",");
                             String lat=latlng[0];
                             String lng=latlng[1];
                             System.out.println("Lat "+lat+" Lng "+lng);
                        }
                    }
```

Here is the complete parsing code section.

Answer (score 0):

Try to parse your JSON response as below:

```
JSONArray arra = new JSONArray("stores");
 for(int i=0;i<arra.length();i++)
  {
   JSONObject json = arra.getJSONObject(i);
   //Retrieve the data from the JSON object
   String name= json.getString("name");
   String points = json.getString("point");
   String loc=json.getString("LS");
}
```

**EDITED:**

Extract the lat,long from string point you need to use the `StringTokenizer` to split the string as below:

```
   StringTokenizer stoken = new StringTokenizer(points, ",");
    while (stoken.hasMoreTokens()) {
           System.err.println(stoken.nextToken());
   }
```

Comment: thank you GirsHu
i checked this one, getting out put properly.
can u tell me how to extract lat and lang from a string "point".?